# Android WebView loadDataWithBaseURL link href not supporting

Tags: android, android-webview, href

I have loaded HTML to my WebView with

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", getHTMLString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

I want to open some pages using anchor  Tag, but this is not working and showing error:

```
<li ><a href="about_us.html" class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">About Us</a></li>
<li ><a href="contact_us.html" class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Contact Us</a></li>
```

is it possible which I want to apply or not ?? I want to avoid open new builtin Browser, pages should be behave like part of application, here is getHTMLString() method

```
String getHTMLString()
{
    String htmlString = "<HTML><Head><BODY>
    <ul>
    <li ><a href=\"about_us.html\" class=\"gn-icon gn-icon-download\">About Us</a></li>
    <li ><a href=\"contact_us.html\" class=\"gn-icon gn-icon-download\">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </BODY></HEAD></HTML>";
    return htmlString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `WebViewClient` with overrided `onLoadResource`.
Once I've added this into my code, all pages started to open in the same `WebView`:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
    });
```

If you wouldn't receive such effect, you can parse `url` parameter manually and load needed html pages by yourself.